# Cookie empty on sub pages

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm a cookie newby, but I think this should be relatively easy...

My page has many different entry points (fx. www.mypage.com/entry-one, www.mypage.com/entry-two, www.mypage.com/entry-three).

I need to store the entry url as a cookie when a user enters one of the entry-pages - and set the home button/link to that url during the session. Also, it needs to overwrite if the user enters another entry point. Expiry date should be when the browser closes.

This is what I have. It works if I call on the entry page.

```
setCookie("my-cookie", document.URL);
checkCookie();
```

But on other pages the cookie seems to be empty if I call checkCookie(); again.

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue)
{
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
    alert("The cookie contains " + getCookie("my-cookie") );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way:

```
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue + ";path=/";
```

adding *path=/* makes it available all over.